# Проблема с созданием Excel файла в C#

Tags: c#, windows, excel, datagridview, interop

Проблема заключается в следующем: 
Есть код (ниже показан), который выгружает данные из DataGridView2 в Excel, но в момент создания Excel файла (**xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();**) он крашеться и выдаёт ошибку (под кодом)

Код:

```
private void copyAlltoClipboard()
    {
        dataGridView2.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = dataGridView2.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }

        void Button9Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        }   
    }
```

Ошибка:

> System.InvalidCastException: Невозможно привести COM-объект типа
>   "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass" к интерфейсному типу
>   "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application". Операция завершилась со
>   сбоем, поскольку вызов QueryInterface COM-компонента для интерфейса с
>   IID "{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" возвратил следующую
>   ошибку: Интерфейс не зарегистрирован (Исключение из HRESULT:
>   0x80040155).

Проблема скорее всего в следующем: Раньше на пк стоял Office2007 (был удалён во время разработки проекта) и был установлен Office2016(Коробочная лицензия).

До этого вылетала ошибка, что использую office 12.0.0 версии, а библиотека работает на 15.0.0 версии (я это фиксил путём переименования папки с 12.0.0 на 15.0.0)

Задача в следующем:
как это всё по фиксить без переустановки Window's, office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь reference на офис правильной версии в свойства проекта.

Переименование папок - это ерунда.

Comment: Я это сделал: нашёл в **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\Microsoft Power Query for Excel Integrated\bin"**, но всё равно выдаёт ошибку тоже самую

Comment: @ElemStack, а если сделать то, что я написал?

Comment: У меня русской версии программа SharpDevelop. Reference - это и есть вроде бы ссылка, я её в среде обновил на тот "где путь написал выше коментом" и пересобрал проект.

Comment: Проблема решена, это был косяк со стороны винды, который не давал доступ к Excel (они вылетали при запуске)